# Remove API Path in Visual Basic Web API Controller

Tags: vb.net

I have a Web API Controller written in Visual Basic

```
Public Class VersionController Inherits ApiController

Public Function GetVersion() As String
  Return "Hello World"
End Function

End Class
```

In the Global.asax, I added

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApi", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}")
End Sub
```

As a result, the following url works:

- localhost\api\version

However, I need to avoid using the api route, is there a way to exclude that path use a custom one instead: localhost\version

Comment: You could use the route attribute on individual endpoints https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: That looks like what I need, but is there an example for VB? I can't seem to implement this because I can't find some of the dependencies mentioned, Route, WebApiConfig, etc.